# Store data in Variable for Array of Arrays for creating a flat array in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to access the data of Array inside an array and save it to further flatten, my function requires the arrays to be flatten.

But When I try to access all the objects, it is giving me undefined error. Below is the error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

**This is how I am trying to access it:**

`let filterbrands = this.props.tvfilter.brand[0].options` OR `let filterbrands = this.props.tvfilter.brand.options`

**Function to Flatten:**

```
const mult = [filterbrands, [{id: 112, name: "Chop Suey", artist: "System of a Down" }]];

const flatMult = mult.reduce((acc, currValue) => {
return acc.concat(currValue);
}, []);
```

**Below is my JSON Format:**

```
{
  "brand": [
     {

    "title": "Brands",
    "options": [
    {
     "catgeory_name": "Sigma"
    },
    {
     "catgeory_name": "Footner"
    }
   ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Desired Result should be like the below output after flatten:

```
{catgeory_name: "Sigma", category_id: "755"}
{catgeory_name: "Footner", category_id: "611"}
{catgeory_name: "Young Blood", category_id: "591"}
{id: 112, name: "Chop Suey", artist: "System of a Down"}
```

Comment: what is the result you need?

Comment: can you add how your `tvfilter` looks like ?

Comment: @dfsq : Updated the question, please check for desired output.

Comment: @CodeManiac : i hope you mean to say `tvfilter` response, If I log this `let filterbrands = this.props.tvfilter.brand` in console, check the following image for log. [https://i.imgur.com/8dVF98t.jpg]